# Forcing NonLinearModelFit through a point

Tags: fitting, data

Like the title says, is there a way to make an NLM fit pass through a specific point.

Comment: You can add a constraint to your model.

Comment: like what? I've tried specifying a value but it doesn't work.

Comment: Or do a weighted fit with a very large weight for your point.

Comment: The question is hastily written with not a tremendous amount of thought put in to it; however, I think it is a valid question and worthy of staying open since setting this type of constraint isn't always obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
data = Table[{i, i}, {i, 10}];
model = a + b x ^2;
```

Unrestricted model:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b}, x] // Normal
```

> $ 0.0863422 x^2+2.17582 $

Model restricted to pass through `{5,5}`:

```
nlmr = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, (model /. x -> 5 ) == 5}, {a, b}, x] // Normal
```

> $ 0.0790502 x^2+3.02375 $

Picture:

```
Show[Plot[{nlm, nlmr}, {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"nlm", "nlmr"}],
 ListPlot[Labeled[#, #, Top] & /@ data],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{5, 5}]}]]
```

[image]

You could also do:

```
model2[x_] := a + b x ^2;
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, model2[x], {a, b}, x] // Normal 
nlmr2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model2[x], model2[5] == 5}, {a, b}, x] // Normal
```

You can also have multiple constraints, e.g., can force the fit to pass through two points `{1,1}` and `{7,7}`:

```
nlmr2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
           {model2[x], model2[1] == 1 && model2[7] == 7}, {a, b}, x] // Normal

Show[Plot[{nlm2, nlmr2}, {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"nlm2", "nlmr2"}],
     ListPlot[Labeled[#, #, Top] & /@ data],
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{1, 1}, {7, 7}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: ok thanks. I thought it was model[5]==5 ?

Comment: @Dan, thanks for the accept. You can also use that form if you previously defined `model` as a function (i.e. `model[x_]:= ... ` as opposed to `model = ...`).

Comment: ok. now it seems a bit clearer. Thanks again

Comment: @Dan, my pleasure.